# Hide part after 5 seconds after mousedown action

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python. I programmed with vb2010, but it's time to try something new. I want to hide a action after 5 seconds after mouse down event(like in start()).

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
from time import gmtime, strftime
import threading
import time
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
width = 600
height = 400
channel = '0001'
name = 'Channel 3'
class screen(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        pygame.display.set_caption('PyTV')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((black))
        pygame.display.update()

    def printData(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (blue), (0, 0, width, height - 350), 0)
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(channel, True, white), (width - 590, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(name, True, white), (height - 335, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y", gmtime()), True, white), (width - 590, height - 377))
        pygame.display.update()

    def clean(self):
        self.screen.fill((black))
        pygame.display.update()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def start():
        Pan3.printData()
        time.sleep(5)
        Pan3.clean()
    Pan3 = screen()
    threading.Thread(target=start).start()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print 'Event! Mouse Down! Code here....'
```

Comment: Any specific reason why time.sleep(5) doesn't fit your needs here? Also, if it is relevant to your problem, what do you mean with "I want to hide a action"?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Note that this _isn't_ a forum, it's a question and answer site, so you shouldn't ask two separate questions on the one question page. Also, asking people here to help you quickly is a good way to annoy them.

Comment: Mouse down Event > wait 5 sec > hide
if another event is happening(another mouse down event while the first one) Hide it and repeat...
My english is bad!

Comment: Ok. Fix on the way, PM 2Ring. But I tried Pygame with vlc and got error. Also need to open stream local from vlc pygame.

Comment: `Queue`? https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Comment: Jaroslaw, And what I do with queue?!? I need some way to control the show procedure like in def start() in screen class.

Comment: Let's just concentrate on your "hide a action after 5 seconds" issue, ok? You can ask about streaming from VLC into Pygame in your next question. If you don't understand _why_ I'm telling you this stuff you need to read the [help] pages more thoroughly.

Comment: Ok! I don't speak very well english!

Comment: see how to use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to control elements - ie. to show/hide something: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40727968/1832058

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click `left mouse` first time then it shows date, when you click second time then it hides date. If you don't click second time then it hides automatically after 5 seconds.

The same with key `SPACE` - first press shows, second hides. If you don't press second time then it hides automatically after 5 seconds.

Key `ESC` and `right click` hides too.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
BLUE  = (  0,  0,255)

WIDTH  = 600
HEIGHT = 400

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Screen(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)

        pygame.display.set_caption('PyTV')

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)

        self.channel = '0001'
        self.name = 'Channel 3'

        self.show_data = None
        self.current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()


    def draw_data(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, BLUE, (0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT-350), 0)
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.channel, True, WHITE), (WIDTH-590, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(self.name, True, WHITE), (HEIGHT-335, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S %d/%m/%Y", time.gmtime()), True, WHITE), (WIDTH-590, HEIGHT-377))


    def events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                return False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    self.show_data = None
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    if self.show_data:
                        self.show_data = None
                    else:
                        self.show_data = self.current_time + 5000

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    if self.show_data:
                        self.show_data = None
                    else:
                        self.show_data = self.current_time + 5000
                elif event.button == 3:
                    # hide on right click
                    self.show_data = None

    def update(self):

        # if displayed
        if self.show_data:
            # check time
            if self.current_time >= self.show_data:
                # hide after time
                self.show_data = None


    def draw(self):

        self.screen.fill(BLACK)

        if self.show_data:
            self.draw_data()

        pygame.display.update()


    def run(self): # mainloop

        while True:

            self.current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.events() is False:
                break

            self.update()

            self.draw()

        #sys.exit()

# --- fucntions --- (lower_case names)

# empty

# --- main ---

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Screen().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

A [timer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#timer-objects) may suit your needs, given that you also use threading.

EDIT: Addressing your needs for a more detailed explanation as to how to get it to work, here's some pseudo-code.

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if active_timer:
        timer.cancel()
    timer = Timer(5.0, show_info_things)
    timer.start()
```

I hope this gets you going well enough.

Comment: Look, everyone. I will make a short video about how it should work. I just need a hour to complete it. Can you wait?!?

Comment: Sure, I can wait, the question is whether it is worth your time and effort. Judging from your comment, it seems that this is not sufficient yet. Can you try to explain what other functionality you need?

Comment: VLC from localhost stream in pygame and this.

Comment: @talnacialexandru_vb2010 We don't _want_ a video. You need to explain your problem clearly in _words_. You can add a video or image link to your question to help enhance your explanation, but the question needs to be clear without those links.

Comment: For the VLC part, you should ask a different question. If my solution fixes this part of your problem, consider marking it as accepted to let others know this worked for you.

Comment: And also SP-SC-AUTH Stream signal strength

Comment: Gif on the way!

Comment: Now rendering in sony vegas... then gif maker then here.

Comment: SHT! Gif site not wanting! Trying video instead to gif.

Comment: I would call start()?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/PyTVMain.py", line 47, in <module>
    if active_timer:
NameError: name 'active_timer' is not defined

Comment: Note that I said pseudo-code. You will need some additional logic to see if there actually is an active timer. Note that SO is meant to ask for help on problems you're having, not to ask for complete code.

Comment: OKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK?