# Blinking rectangle white pygame with specific frequency

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles

I'm student at university and I have a specific question.

Presently I display a white rectangle in center of a window with pygame above a black background. But presently I would like to blinking my white rectangle at a specific frequency, and it's why a I need help.

Presently I implement that:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
    pygame.init()

    fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)

    black=(0,0,0)
    white=(255,255,255)

    fenetre.fill(black)

    pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, white,(200,150,100,50))


    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

[image]

Thanks for your help community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very popular method to control elements is using time.

You set time of next change state and then you compare this with current time. This way you control object and you don't stop `while True` loop so it cando other things.

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- main ---

def main():
    pygame.init()

    fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)

    # time in millisecond from start program 
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # how long to show or hide
    delay = 500 # 500ms = 0.5s

    # time of next change 
    change_time = current_time + delay
    show = True

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # --- updates ---

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        # is time to change ?
        if current_time >= change_time:
            # time of next change 
            change_time = current_time + delay
            show = not show

        # --- draws ---

        fenetre.fill(BLACK)

        if show:
            pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, WHITE,(200,150,100,50))

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

---

**EDIT:** the same with more elements

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)

# --- main ---

def main():
    pygame.init()

    fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # time of show or hide
    delay = 500 # 500ms = 0.5s

    # time of next change (WHITE)
    change_time = current_time + delay
    show = True

    # time of next change (RED)
    red_change_time = current_time + delay + 150
    red_show = False

    # time of next change (GREEN)
    green_change_time = current_time + delay + 300
    green_show = False

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # --- updates ---

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        # is time to change ? (WHITE)
        if current_time >= change_time:
            change_time = current_time + delay
            show = not show

        # is time to change ? (RED)
        if current_time >= red_change_time:
            red_change_time = current_time + delay
            red_show = not red_show

        # is time to change ? (GREEN)
        if current_time >= green_change_time:
            green_change_time = current_time + delay
            green_show = not red_show

        # --- draws ---

        fenetre.fill(BLACK)

        if show: # (WHITE)
            pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, WHITE, (200,150,100,50))

        if red_show: # (RED)
            pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, RED, (100,150,100,50))

        if green_show: # (GREEN)
            pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, GREEN, (300,150,100,50))

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

---

**EDIT:** version using class. But this time with different frequencies

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants ---

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)

# --- classes ---

class Rectangle():

    def __init__(self, color, rect, time, delay):
        self.color = color
        self.rect = rect
        self.time = time
        self.delay = delay
        self.show = False

    def draw(self, screen):
        if self.show:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect)

    def update(self, current_time):
        if current_time >= self.time:
             self.time = current_time + self.delay
             self.show = not self.show

# --- main ---

def main():
    pygame.init()

    fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # time of show or hide
    delay = 500 # 5000ms = 0.5s

    # objects    
    rect_white = Rectangle(WHITE, (200,150,100,50), current_time, 500)
    rect_red = Rectangle(RED, (100,150,100,50), current_time + 150, 100)
    rect_green = Rectangle(GREEN, (0, 0, 500, 400), current_time + 300, 2000)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        # --- updates ---

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        rect_white.update(current_time)
        rect_red.update(current_time)
        rect_green.update(current_time)

        # --- draws ---

        fenetre.fill(BLACK)

        rect_green.draw(fenetre)
        rect_white.draw(fenetre)
        rect_red.draw(fenetre)

        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Comment: I will try that, thank for you proposition, it's limpid

Comment: @SofianeM'barki I added version using class.

Comment: It's work very fine, thanks for you different proposition and point of view @furas. That will help me a lot, thank you.

Comment: Good answer. didn't know that one.

Answer (score 1):

I made some edits to your code to fit your needs and tested it.

### The Code

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

fenetre = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

frequency = 1


def main():

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, black, (200, 150, 100, 50))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(frequency)
        pygame.draw.rect(fenetre, white, (200, 150, 100, 50))
        pygame.display.update()
        time.sleep(frequency)
        clock.tick(30)


main()
```

*The result should be the rect appearing each 1 sec*

Comment: Using `time.sleep` in your main loop is really a bad idea. You can do nothing while waiting for `time.sleep` to finish, so your entire application will be blocked (you can't even close the window while wainting).

Comment: Hmmm true enough. but that's what I could do as far as his request goes. if you have any alternatives, please share them with us.